# How to change the <img> tag for displaying smiley/emoticons so that the same smiley/emoticon could be displayed on smart devices?

Tags: android, ios, image, emoticons

I'm basically a **PHP developer** by profession. I've no idea about iOS and Android coding at all.

I've developed an API in PHP which returns some data. This data is used by website, iOS app and Android app.

For example, if we take sample output of one such data element it would look as follows :

```
$feed_status = How are you all boys <img src=\"http://52.1.47.143/file/pic/emoticon/default/smile.png\" alt=\"Smile\" title=\"Smile\" title=\"v_middle\" />;
```

If I show this data on a website the smiley/emoticon looks perfect as the `<img>` tag has got the path for concerned image.

But my issue is when the same data(smiley/emoticon) is displayed on iPhone and Android devices the `<img>` tag displays as it is. The respective smiley symbol doesn't get appear on these devices.

If you hit the `URL : http://52.1.47.143/file/pic/emoticon/default/smile.png` in your browser you could see the respective smiley image.

I want to show the same smiley/emoticon image on smart devices running on iOS and Android. How should I do this? Can someone please help me by providing efficient and optimum solution for this?

Thanks for spending some of your valuable time in understanding my issue.

If you need any further information regarding the issue I'm facing please do let me know. I'd be more than happy to convey you the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue is in the application its self. That URL needs to be whitelisted. I'm guessing they're using Cordova/Phonegap.

Comment: Are you working with native or any other framework like phonegap or titanium?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, @N J Gadhiya : The website from which I'm getting the data has been developed using PHPFox framework.

Comment: You said that it's used by an `ios/android app`. That application needs to do the white listing, not the PHP.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy:Actually the iOS and Android apps are using data from the website which has been developed using PHPFox. This data the app is receiving through the API that I developed using PHP. So what should I do on PHP side in order to display the same smiley/emoticon on smart devices? The task has been assigned to me to give them the proper response so that they could show the smiley/emoticon in their app.

Comment: They need to whitelist that IP address in the application. If they don't have wildcard whitelisting, then they need to whitelist the IP address that you've provided.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy:First of all thanks for your help. But frankly speaking I dodn't understand by whitelisting you are talking about. If you could post your thoughts in the form of an answer in more precise manner it would be really helpful to me as well as other community members who may face the same issue. Could you please do me a favor and answer my question? Thanks once again.

Comment: Is this a Native Android / iOS application, or is this an Cordova / Phonegap application they're building?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy:These are native Android and iOS applications. They have not used Cordova or Phonegap.